# First open limited item not all in jQuery Quicksand?

Tags: jquery, quicksand

**jQuery Quicksand**

*I want to first open limited item like "vogue". in here ist open "all"*
*What the change in the programs? Please help me*

*For looking*
[go here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435870/jquery-quicksand)

[go here2](http://www.bryanflopez.me/work)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want all to show all items when you open the page, you can call the `.quicksand()` function for `.vouge` on page load, to trigger the filtering/animation.

Since the example with "vogue" is not trivial, I chose to reuse the click event handler. Put this code last in your javascript.

```
$(function() {
    // It would be better to create a function for this, but
    // to avoid code duplication the click() event is triggered/reused
    $('#filterOptions li a.vogue').click();
});
```

This is of course only a quick fix. It would be better to create a proper function of the contents of the click event, and call the function both on load and on click.

Comment: @prodipsarkar55: Please keep the question to stackoverflow if you want help. No need to contact me through email, just edit your own question with more info.